# Can't run functions in sequence. Python

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I'm working on Tkinter and my goal is to when the user presses a button it opens a new window that he can insert data on database and then it populates a table again so it shows the new data inserted. The new window opens fine and data is indeed inserted, but the list is not updated and I don't know why.

Button code:

```
self.inserir = Button(self.container2, text="Inserir", command=lambda:self.help(tm.FazTela(bd),self.populate()))
```

Function code that gets the functions as a list and run them:

```
def help(*functions):
    def func(*args, **kwargs):
        return_value = None
        for function in functions:
            return_value = function(*args, **kwargs)
        return return_value
    return func
```

If I call the populate function before the function that generates the window it runs nicely but that's not what I want, I want to update after the user has input data.

I don't know if it helps, but here's the code of the window that opens once the button is pressed:

```
from Tkinter import *
from database import database as db
from database import tratamentos as tr
import tkMessageBox
class TelaMenor():

def __init__(self):
    self.root = None
    self.OPTIONS = []
    self.cor1 = '#D32F2F'

def CloseWindow(self):
    self.root.destroy()
    self.root = None


def SendToTR(self,nome,valor,tipo,bd):
    try:
        tr.ProdutosRecieve(nome,valor,tipo,bd)
    except:
        tkMessageBox.showerror("Erro encontrado", "Digite valores validos!")
    finally:
        self.CloseWindow()


def FazTela(self,bd):
    if(self.root!=None):
        self.CloseWindow()
        self.FazTela()
    else:
        self.root=Tk()
        # opcoes do droplist
        self.OPTIONS = [
            "Tipo de produto",
            "Doce",
            "Salgado",
            "Massa",
            "Bebida",
            "Outro"
            ]
        #fim
        # criacao e posicao dos widgets
        info = Frame(self.root)
        info.grid(sticky=N+S+W+E)

        salto1 = Label(info, text="       ")
        salto1.grid(row=0, column=0)

        nome1 = Label(info, text="Nome:")
        nome1['font']=['bold']
        nome1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

        nome2 = Entry(info)
        nome2["width"]=40
        nome2.grid(row=2, column=1)
        salto2 = Label(info, text="")
        salto2.grid(row=3, column=0)

        valor1 = Label(info, text="Valor:")
        valor1['font']=['bold']
        valor1.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W)

        valor2 = Entry(info)
        valor2["width"]=40
        valor2.grid(row=5, column=1)

        salto3 = Label(info, text="")
        salto3.grid(row=6, column=0)

        variable = StringVar(info)
        variable.set(self.OPTIONS[0])

        droplist = apply(OptionMenu, (info, variable) + tuple(self.OPTIONS))
        droplist.grid(row=7, column=1)

        salto4 = Label(info, text="")
        salto4.grid(row=8, column=0)

        pronto = Button(info, text="Pronto", bg=self.cor1, bd=3,command=lambda: self.SendToTR(nome2.get(),valor2.get(),variable.get(),bd))
        pronto['font']=['bold']
        pronto['fg']='white'
        pronto.grid(row=9, column=1)

        salto5 = Label(info, text="")
        salto5.grid(row=10, column=1)

        espaco1 = Label(info, text="       ")
        espaco1.grid(row=10, column=2)
        #fim

        # barra de "status"
        status = Label(info, text="Estado: Normal", bg="white", bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W)
        status.grid(row= 11, column=0, sticky=S+W+E, columnspan=3)
        #fim

        # formatacao da janela
        self.root.title('Cadastro do Produto')
            #root.iconbitmap(r'c:\Python27\DLLs\icon.ico')
        self.root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        self.root.geometry('298x276')
        self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",lambda: self.CloseWindow())
        self.root.mainloop()
        #fim
```

Sorry, there are some words in portuguese.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good illustration of why you shouldn't use lambda unless absolutely necessary: it makes debugging difficult. I recommend removing the use of lambda, and instead tie the button to a normal function. Doing so will make it easier to insert debugging code.

In this case, your function is running this code:

```
self.help(tm.FazTela(bd),self.populate())
```

This is the same as doing this:

```
a = tm.FazTela(bd)
b = self.populate()
self.help(a,b)
```

You also have the problem that you are creating more than one root window. In tkinter you must always have exactly one root window. Instead of creating a second instance of `Tk`, you need to create an instance of `Toplevel`.

If you want to execute code after the window has been destroyed you can use the function `wait_window` which will not return until the given window has closed.